# File.ReadAllBytes takes a lot of RAM, is there a better way?

Tags: c#

I am busy working with an encryption lib, and I want to encrypt large files (with AES GCM). Currently I have this for encrypting files, after writing a temp file, `Chipher`, from the `CryptoStream`:

```
byte[] Chiper = File.ReadAllBytes(BUFFER_PATH);

                    // Retrieve tag and create array to hold encrypted data.
                    byte[] AuthTag = encryptor.GetTag();
                    byte[] encrypted = new byte[Chiper.Length + aes.IV.Length + AuthTag.Length];

                    // Set needed data in byte array.
                    aes.IV.CopyTo(encrypted, 0);
                    AuthTag.CopyTo(encrypted, IV_LENGTH);
                    Chiper.CopyTo(encrypted, IV_LENGTH + TAG_LENGTH);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(END_PATH, encrypted);
```

This function works fine, however it takes a lot of RAM depending on the filesize. Is there a better way though this? I tried using a `FileStream`  though it starts conflicting with my code. Is there a way to use less, or no memory to save `Chiper(byte[])`?

Comment: Is there a way of outputting the CryptoStream directly into the output file, rather than having the intermediary temporary file stage?

Comment: `CryptoStream`s were made for this

Comment: A `Stream` of some kind is what you need; how does that “starts conflicting with my code”?

Comment: @DourHighArch I tried to get multiple parameters (like length) but I can't seem to get them. Or I am lacking experience

Comment: Show your code that opens and writes to `BUFFER_PATH`.  There's probably a simple way to write the tag and IV by slightly modifying that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're trying to write a composite file that has three pieces of information - the tag, IV and cipher text.  Given that you can't get the tag value until after the encryption completes, you are trying to composite the data after encryption completes.

The problem comes in when you attempt to load a large encrypted file into memory.  Fortunately, streams provide a nice simple solution for this:

```
byte[] authTag = encryptor.GetTag();

using (var tempfile = File.OpenRead(BUFER_PATH))
using (var outstream = File.Create(END_PATH))
{
    // write tag
    outstream.Write(authTag, 0, authTag.Length);
    // write IV
    outstream.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);
    // copy data from source file to output file
    tempfile.CopyTo(outstream);
}
```

On the other hand you could also write the data straight to the output file if you know ahead of time what size the tag and IV are going to be.  Just allocate space for the tag value at the start of the file and come back and write it in after the fact.  That saves you having to use a temporary file.